# Create table and scheme postgres using docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I am trying to create a postgres database with schema and table in it using docker- compose file.

I have read some posts regarding this topic and tried the suggested solutions:
Copying the .sql files into the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ using a volume as they should get executed.

My docker- compose is:

```
  postgres_db:
       image: postgres:latest
       hostname: postgres-db
       container_name: postgres
       expose:
         - "5432"
       ports:
         - "5432:5432"
       networks:
         - default
       environment:
         - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
         - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
         - "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
       volumes:
         - ./scripts/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

the files in /scripts/postgres are:

```
1-schema.sql

CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
```

```
2-table.sql

CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable(id integer PRIMARY KEY, purchase_date date, unit integer, description varchar(300));
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
postgres       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
postgres       | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql:0: could not read from input file: Is a directory
postgres exited with code 1
```

Also I tried to define the volumes as:

```
       volumes:
         - ./scripts/postgres/1-schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
         - ./scripts/postgres/2-table.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-table.sql
```

but still getting same error :(

Any suggestion about why is it failing and a possible fix?

EDIT: 
@Mihai, it doesn't seems that there is a folder named 1-schema.sql. Below the output of the proposed command:

```
$ ls -lart ./scripts/postgres
total 16
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff   26 13 may 22:21 1-schema.sql
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  152 13 may 22:21 2-table.sql
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  staff  128 13 may 22:43 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 user  staff  288 13 may 22:50 ..

$ cat ./scripts/postgres/1-schema.sql
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
$ cat ./scripts/postgres/2-table.sql
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable(id integer PRIMARY KEY, purchase_date date, unit integer, description varchar(300));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recreated your example and it works perfectly. Are you on Windows? Because then it might be a file format issue.

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for your response. I am executing it on OS X. 
And I am executing the following comands:

 `docker-compose down`
 `docker-compose build`
 `docker-compose up`

Comment: From the error it looks like it sees the file as a directory. That normally happens with a wrong COPY or ADD command but you are not using a Dockerfile. So it must be something with your file structure. Can you try and rename 1-schema.sql to 01_schema.sql and the other file similarly and run it again? Also you can remove "network" and "expose" declarations from docker-compose.yml because they don't add any value.

Comment: @Mihai, I also tried to rename the file as you said without success:
`$ ls -lart ./scripts/postgres
total 16
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff   26 13 may 22:21 01_schema.sql
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  152 13 may 22:21 02_table.sql
drwxr-xr-x  9 user  staff  288 13 may 22:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  staff  128 14 may 19:21 .`
And the volumes in docker compose as:
       `  - ./scripts/postgres/01_schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_schema.sql
         - ./scripts/postgres/02_table.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02_table.sql `

Comment: But same result:

`
postgres       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_schema.sql
postgres       | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_schema.sql:0: could not read from input file: Is a directory
postgres exited with code 1
`

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't say rename. I said delete them and create them all new. The "@" should disappear.

Comment: Sorry, this was the answer to your previous comment about trying to rename from 1-schema.sql to 01_schema.sql. I'll try now to remove and create the files and lets see if the @ character disappears. I'll let you know. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue by creating and actual folder:

```
mkdir ./scripts/postgres/0-schema.sql
docker-compose up
```

Then I get exactly your error:

```
postgres       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-schema.sql
postgres       | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-schema.sql:0: could not read from input file: Is a directory
```

Double check your local setup because you might have a folder called 1-schema.sql in your "scripts/postgres" folder.
Check this by running in your project folder:

```
ls -lart ./scripts/postgres
```

Comment: it doesn't seems that there is a folder named 1-schema.sql, added the output of that command in the post ( too long to add it as a comment) thanks! :)

Comment: the only problem I can see is the '@' character at the end: "-rw-r--r--@". This means extended attributes and you can see them by running "ls -lart@". but before that can you just recreate the files so that the "@" symbol disappears? It could be that this makes the file appear as a directory in linux... So remove the files and create them again with vim or some other text editor you have.

Comment: No luck...
Now the '@' disapear but I still get the same error of the directory

`$ ls -lart ./scripts/postgres
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  9 user  staff  288 14 may 19:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   27 14 may 19:54 01_schema.sql
drwxr-xr-x  4 user  staff  128 14 may 19:54 .
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  153 14 may 19:54 02_table.sql`

`postgres       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_schema.sql
postgres       | psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_schema.sql:0: could not read from input file: Is a directory
postgres exited with code 1`

Comment: man this is one problem.... :) Can you please run this: "docker-compose run postgres_db ls -lart /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d". This will overwrite the entrypoint and instead of trying to run the scripts will how us what is in that directory inside the container. Looking forward to see the output :)

Comment: All files there:

$ docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml run postgres_db ls -lart /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   64 May 13 21:08 2-table.sql
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   64 May 13 21:08 1-schema.sql
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   64 May 14 17:32 02_table.sql
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   64 May 14 17:32 01_schema.sql
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  192 May 14 17:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 14 18:16 ..

Comment: all there and as directories..... Now let's see what is inside these directories: "docker-compose run postgres_db ls -lart /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02_table.sql" Can you run this? Further more, these are exactly the files you see in local as well right?

Comment: Yep... seems so... 

They are empty:
$ docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml run postgres_db ls -lart /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02_table.sql
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 192 May 14 17:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  64 May 14 17:32 .

$ docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml run postgres_db ls -lart /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_schema.sql
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 192 May 14 17:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  64 May 14 17:32 .

In local I have those files with those names, but as files not as directories

Comment: I see now the problem... You were not completely honest :) You MUST run the docker-compose in the same folder with the docker-compose.yml and your files. You should not have to add the "-f" flag with the path to the docker-compose.yml file. You can always use "docker-compose config" to see the exact version that is running. THis will also contain the FULL PATH TO THE SCRIPTS on host. If that path does not exist this is HOW you end up with empty directories inside your container.

Comment: I see :D now it is executing correctly!! thanks a lot for being so helpful in the troubleshooting :)) just to confirm ( as I am quite new in dockers) the best practice is to execute always the docker-compose from the folder where is the docker-compose.yml, right? If I want to use the -f flag I need to write the volume with the absolute path to scripts in the local host?

Comment: yes, you could say that. Try to get used to run "docker-compose config". You can even run it with "docker-compose -f some_file.yml config". And analyse well the result because that is what will actually run. The problem seemed so trivial at the beginning that I didn't think of this check. Lesson learned ;) Good luck further!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue today, and this is how I solved it.

1. Run `docker-compose -f <file-name.yml> config` to view the actual paths
   being mounted.
2. Check if the scripts are accessible from those paths. If you are running a second docker inside a docker (for example you are building something using Jenkins), use its bash to see if the files are accessible.

In my case, they were not accessible. I changed the path and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder created locally which was causing conflicts. As soon as I removed it from my project structure the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Docker Compose `compose.yaml` file, for use with [the official Postgres Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) ...

In it, I use the [long syntax of `volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-5).

```
services:
  # ...  
  database:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      # ...
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: db_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      - type: bind
        source: ./pg/init-user-db.sql
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sql
        read_only: true

volumes:
  db_data:
```

One probably could get this to work using the [short syntax for `volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#short-syntax-5), but that would be less readable IMO.

Advantages and differences from other examples you'll find around the web:

- This syntax makes it abundantly clear that it is a **bind** not a **volume**.
- Using a `.sql` file is easier to read and maintain and works fine.
- Making the file read-only is deliberate. IMO, the proper place to edit the file is in my source code.